# ¿Hacer dos tablas relacionadas con una variable que vaya a una tabla u otra función de la variable en una base de datos con MySQL?

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, tablas, relaciones

Si tengo una lista e pacientes de un hospital por ejemplo, y quiero separarlos por sexo porque dependiendo de esto la información que quiero guardar es distinta.
Lo primero que haría, sería una tabla PACIENTES con la información de la persona: Nombre, Apellido... dentro de esta tabla pondría la variable sexo.

Mi primera pregunta es, ¿puedo poner que sexo sea una variable que en la que solo se pueda poner: masculino o femenino?

Por otro lado, imaginemos que ya hemos elegido mujer, puedo ir a una tabla donde solo guardo información de las mujeres poniendo como restricción el resultado de sexo? 
Por ejemplo, de la tabla pacientes obtengo que es mujer, entonces voy a la tabla correspondiente para este sexo y guardo por ejemplo el valor de un análisis de hormonas (que solo tienen las mujeres)

Comment: La respuesta a la primera pregunta es [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html). La segunda pregunta no la entiendo muy bien, porque eso parece un simple `JOIN` usando un `WHERE` o un `ON` donde `sexo = 'femenino'`.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta a la primera pregunta es [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html). Te permite crear campos que contienen únicamente un conjunto de valores prefijados y no puede contener ningún otro valor (exceptuando `NULL` si así lo permitimos):

```
CREATE TABLE pacientes (
    -- Resto de campos
    sexo ENUM('masculino', 'femenino')
)
```

La segunda pregunta no la entiendo muy bien, porque eso parece un simple `JOIN` usando un `WHERE` o un `ON` donde `sexo = 'femenino'`. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM pacientes p
LEFT JOIN tabla_mujeres tm
  ON tm.idpaciente = p.id
WHERE
  p.sexo = 'femenino'
```

También puedes crear relacionar dos tablas diferentes (en el siguiente ejemplo se llaman `tabla_A` y `tabla_B`) y obtener los datos de ellas simultáneamente:

```
SELECT * FROM pacientes p
LEFT JOIN tabla_A ta
  ON p.sexo = 'femenino' AND p.id = ta.idpaciente
LEFT JOIN tabla_B tb
  ON p.sexo = 'masculino' AND p.id = tb.idpaciente
```

Aquellos campos que no existan porque el usuario es del sexo opuesto (o bien porque no están agregados) aparecerán como `NULL`.

Se puede ver un ejemplo en línea [pulsando aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkEHy2mPE1YDomiBfxkEHd/0).

Por último, se pueden crear vistas de las tablas para hacer búsquedas por cada sexo que contengan únicamente los campos de cada uno de ellos.

Comment: ¿La herencia (claves foráneas) quieres que sean automáticas a una tabla u otra dependiendo del sexo? ¿Has comprobado las formas normales que cumple tu base de datos?

Comment: Si, quiero que directamente teniendo en cuneta el sexo se dirija a una tabla u otra

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿quieres que al introducir con un `INSERT` campos de una tabla cuando el sexo sea uno u otro se inserten el resto de campos en las tablas correspondientes? ¿Qué uso quieres darle a la consulta? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de los datos que vas a guardar en la pregunta editándola?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que si me dicen que la persona es mujer, en una tabla correspondiente a este sexo se guarden los datos para este sexo.

Comment: ¿Pero en tu programa lo guardarás en esa tabla o quieres que lo haga automáticamente el `INSERT` porque en él proporcionarás los campos de uno u otro sexo?

Comment: Sí, lo gardaré en esa tabla. Es decir, tengo tabla pacientes, si me dice que es femenino me voy a la tabla de la información femenina y allí guardo la información correspondiente a la analítica para esa mujer.

Comment: Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema que estás teniendo exactamente? ¿qué es lo que no te funciona para tener dos tablas para obtener los datos cruzados usando un `JOIN`?

Comment: creo que ya lo he solucionado ultilizando una tabla dinámica. gracias

Comment: ¿Una tabla dinámica? Redacta tú propia respuesta y así ayudarás a otros con el mismo problema. Yo, personalmente, tengo interés por aprender lo que es una tabla dinámica.

Comment: Ya he redactado la espues, espero que se entiendas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

como te han comentado el primer punto lo puedes utilizar con un ENUM:

```
create table PACIENTES (
    (...)
    sexo ENUM('masculino', 'femenino')
)
```

Si no he entendido mal, ¿en el segundo punto lo que buscas es una herencia?:

```
PACIENTES-> *id, nombre, apellido, edad, sexo (...) [Información general]
PACIENTES_M -> paciente_id_fk [Información específica para hombres]
PACIENTES_F -> paciente_id_fk [Información específica para mujeres]
```

Comment: efectivamente, eso es lo que busco.

Comment: ¿Pero la herencia quieres que sea automática dependiendo del sexo? Voy a seguir comentándote cosas en mi respuesta, agradecería que respondieras mis preguntas para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que he hecho ha sido realizar una tabla dinámica para relacionar el sexo con una determinada variable.

Para eso, tengo la tabla pacientes con Id_paciente y una tabla Campo con su correspondiente ID_campos. En la tabla campos guardo todas las características que vaya a guardar sin tener en cuenta el sexo al que corresponda esta variable.

Para relacionar estas dos, he hecho una tabla con Id_paciente, Id_campo y Valor_del_campo, de esta manera, puedo guardar en esta tabla:
que el paciente 1(siendo esta mujer), en el campo 4(por ejemplo número de embarazos) sea 1. 
Por el contrario, si tengo un paciente 2(hombre), nunca guardaré nada en el Valor_del_campo que corresponda al ID_campo=4

Comment: ¿Podrías usar datos concretos en vez de explicación genérica? Es decir, compartir el SQL exacto que has usado para crear esa tabla dinámica, por ejemplo. Si no se puede reproducir tu respuesta en caso de que otra persona tenga el mismo problema, la respuesta no tiene valor alguno. Cuando la mejores te daré tu primer +1. PD: A grandes rasgos me suena a una relación entre tablas normal y corriente.